# When is a ring homomorphism $A \to A$ surjective but not injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $A$ is Noetherian, a surjective homomorphism from $A$ to itself is necessarily injective.

Thus, it's clear that if $\phi: A \to A$ is surjective, but not injective, the ring in question would have to be non-Noetherian.

Reformulating the question using the first isomorphism theorem. Given $\phi:A \to A$, we know that $A/ \ker \phi \cong \textrm{im} \phi \cong A$. When is it the case that the kernel is nontrivial?

**Related Question:** If every surjective homomorphism $A \to A$ is an isomorphism, does it follow that $A$ is Noetherian?

Comment: As far as I can see the "Related Question" is still unanswered. This is why I don't understand why you accepted a partial answer. Not mentioning that this is way more complicated than other answers which are deleted now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a large class of examples. A continuous map $f : X \to Y$ between compact Hausdorff spaces is injective iff the corresponding pullback map $f^{\ast} : C(Y) \to C(X)$ on spaces of continuous functions to $\mathbb{C}$ is surjective, and dually with injective and surjective switched; this is an aspect of the commutative [Gelfand-Naimark theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation). So it suffices to find an endomorphism $f : X \to X$ of a compact Hausdorff space which is injective but not surjective. An easy example to visualize is an inclusion of a closed interval into a bigger closed interval.

Comment: For a simpler example see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4009133/121097).

Answer (score 3):

The downvoters seem to think I've misunderstood the question.

Consider the ring $A$ of sequences of real numbers, with componentwise addition and multiplication. Then the left shift
$$ (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)\mapsto (a_2,a_3,a_4,\dots) $$
is surjective but not injective.

Comment: My understanding of the post was find a non-Noetherian ring $A$ and a map $\phi:A\to A$ which is surjective but not injective.