# A surjective ring homomorphism which is not an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian, ring-homomorphism

> Give an example of a ring $R$ and a surjective homomorphism $R \to R$ that is not an isomorphism.

Here is my approach. I know a lemma that says that if $R$ is a Noetherian ring, and $f: R \to R$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $f$ is an isomorphism. So the ring $R$ above must be non-Noetherian, which is hard(?) to find, as 'most' rings are Noetherian (or so I've been told in lectures). One example of a non-Noetherian ring that I know is $K[X,Y]/\langle X,XY, XY^2, XY^3, \dots \rangle$, and from this, I was trying to construct such a homomorphism. But I'm stuck; I can see no intuition, and no systematic way to do this except for guessing. Does anyone have a nice solution to this?

Note: I've done some searching, and it seems that upon learning higher mathematics, this is a standard problem. For example, [When is a ring homomorphism $A \to A$ surjective but not injective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933329) has a solution which uses a lot of mathematics that I am unfamiliar with. This problem is from a basic undergraduate algebra course, and I'm trying to work out the answer with only what I know.

Edit: The example of a 'non-noetherian' ring I give above is wrong.

Comment: How about having a polynomial ring with *lots* of variables (and I really mean *lots* of variables), and then getting rid of just a *few* of them, and shuffling the rest?

Comment: @Albert: Still Noetherian. The quotient of a Noetherian ring is always Noetherian. If $K$ is a field, then $K[X,Y]$ is noetherian, hence so is any quotient. The ideal you give is just $(X)$, as $XY^n$ is contained in $(X)$ for all $n\geq 0$.

Comment: If $R$ is Noetherian, then so is $R/I$ for any ideal $I$. If $R$ is Noetherian, then the famous Hilbert Basis Theorem tells you that $R[x]$ is also Noetherian. Inductively, if $R$ is Noetherian, then so is $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ for any positive integer $n$; and fields are Noetherian.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\ldots]$. Consider the map induced by sending $x_1$ to $0\in R$, and sending $x_{k+1}$ to $x_k$ for $k=2,3,4,\ldots$. Verify this gives a surjective ring homomorphism, but that it is not injective (hence not an isomorphism).

Comment: Amazing answer! But what was your intuition behind your solution? (How could someone come up with this, without knowing it beforehand?)

Comment: @Albert: it's an example most people see at some point in their careers, just not necessarily in the context of Noetherian rings. Enumerating a counrable subset of something and defining a "left shift" in this way is a common way to find counterexamples for infinite things which behave nicely in the finite case. For instance, it can be used to generate a surjective linear map which is  not injective (shift a basis and extend linearly).

Answer (score 5):

Analogous to @Arturo's answer, consider a "left-shift" on the infinite product of $\Bbb Z_n$'s say.  That's $(x_1,x_2,\dots)\mapsto(x_2,x_3,\dots)$.

As a corollary, invoking the theorem you mentioned, we have that $\prod_{k=1}^\infty\Bbb Z_n$ is not Noetherian.