# Examples?? Surjective (resp. Injective) ring endomorphisms which aren't isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, artinian

Let f be an endomorphism on a ring R. (assumed unitary & commutative)
We have the following results:

1. R noetherian & f surjective implies f an isomorphism
2. R artinian & f injective implies f an isomorphism

I'm interested in counterexamples to the above when R is not noetherian (resp. artinian).

Further, is there an example of a single ring R with 2 different endomorphisms, one injective and one surjective such that neither are isomorphisms.

My intuition is to perhaps look at infinitely generated algebras over a field/ pid/ "nice ring", however not sure of the details.

Comment: See [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296275/a-surjective-implies-injective-property-for-endomorphism-rings-of-modules). Try to search this site, too.

Comment: [Surjectve and not an isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4009133/742). Same ring has an obvious injective morphism that is not an isomorphism, by doing an "upward shift".